# Howto render QtQuick item into texture

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2, qquickitem

I have a custom `QQuickFramebufferObject` node which renders a texture on some geometry. Now I want to render a Qml item to a texture (e.g. `QOpenGLTexture`) and use this texture in my custom node. I know that there is the `grabToImage` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#grabToImage) method but this method is slow because it first renders everything into a QImage and data has to be transferred from/to the GPU.

In detail, I am looking for something like `ShaderEffectSource` element but with direct access to the texture id which can be used as a texture in the `QQuickFramebufferObject`. Is there already something implemented in Qt for this scenario?